# submit values from radio button

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have 7 questions (7 RadioGroup), with 3 answers for each (21 answers in total). My problem is that my points submited incorrectly. When I'm checking all answers A, submited  points are 18, not 21. Same, when I'm checking all answers B, points are 12, answers C - points 6. I don't understand why, and how to fix it.

**Here's my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.quizapp.question1">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="@string/a1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/a2"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b2"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c2"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a3"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b3"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c3"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a4"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b4"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c4"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a5"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b5"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c5"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question6"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a6"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b6"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c6"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question7"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a7"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b7"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c7"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/so"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/Finish"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pName"
        android:text="0"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="showScore" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scores"
        android:text="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**My java:**

```
public class question1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Necessary to calculate points
    int points = 0;
    TextView scoreTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);

        //Needed to sending total scores to fini.class
        final TextView scoreTextView = ( TextView ) findViewById(R.id.scores);

        //Passing editText value to this activity
        final TextView textView = ( TextView ) findViewById(R.id.pName);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        textView.setText(str);

        //Sending editText value to next activity
        final Button start = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.so);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(question1.this, fini.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", textView.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("scores", scoreTextView.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }


        });

    }


    /**
     * This method is called when we want to calculate points from answers
     */

    public int onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = (( RadioButton ) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.answerA1:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 3;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerB1:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 2;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerC1:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 1;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerA2:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 3;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerB2:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 2;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerC2:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 1;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerA3:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 3;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerB3:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 2;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerC3:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 1;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerA4:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 3;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerB4:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 2;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerC4:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 1;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerA5:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 3;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerB5:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 2;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerC5:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 1;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerA6:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 3;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerB6:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 2;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerC6:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 1;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerA7:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 3;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerB7:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 2;
                }break;
            case R.id.answerC7:
                if (checked) {
                    points = points + 1;
                }break;


        }
        return points;
    }


    public void showScore(View view) {
        scoreTextView.setText(" " + points);

    }
}
```

**Debug kod, when I checked only A answers**

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x79b66e4800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x79b3980040
D/ViewRootImpl@27b6561[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
D/ViewRootImpl@27b6561[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
D/ViewRootImpl@27b6561[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
D/ViewRootImpl@27b6561[MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=71
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=252KB, data=237KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=195KB, data=171KB
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=251KB, data=223KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=251KB, data=223KB
I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@f1f53a3 nm : com.example.android.quizapp ic=null
I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=77
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=91
D/ViewRootImpl@fad30a5[question1]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
```

Comment: Have you done *any* debugging to see where the score gets the incorrect value (specifically checking the `points` variable)?

Comment: I'd suggest using Log.d() while debugging after every call of OnRadioButtonClicked() to check where exactly are you going wrong.
Its hard to help you otherwise as you didn't provide a specific issue (such as an error in your code),

Comment: @codeMagic I pasted code from debug in post. Is it that what you mentioned? I'm totally new in this :)

Comment: @Yashovardhan ok so I pased Log.d() in answers A checked, and now I can see, that my app can't see the first checked.

Comment: 12-28 21:31:01.428 21114-21114/com.example.android.quizapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=71
12-28 21:31:03.837 21114-21114/com.example.android.quizapp D/ViewRootImpl@d7493f4[question1]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0

Comment: @KatarzynaK That gives a big hint. I think the problem has been solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't assigned the onClick `onRadioButtonClicked` to the first RadioGroup with the ids `answerA1`, `answerB1` and `answerC1`

---

In your layout, check the `RadioButton` for the first `RadioGroup`. The first three answers are missing the line `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"` in their layout. Compare

```
<RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="@string/a1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
```

with

```
 <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/a2"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
```

Comment: I personally don't think this the most optimal way of creating the layout. If you have same 7 layouts, consisting of 3 repeating layouts (answers), I would suggest making them dynamically through a for loop in the activity class. And no problem